# ICICI Bank Eazypay integration in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel-8, payment-gateway

Can I use Eazypay php code in Laravel 10 for my website payment transaction, if not can anyone guide me to integrate Eazypay in Laravel 10. I don't find any proper guidance from anywhere.

I have php code but can't get Laravel 10 code .